# When is UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout function sizeForItemAt called

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift5

I am trying to programmatically change the size of collection cells dynamically based on orientation. I am using to use the `sizeForItemAt` function to do so, but I am only finding it being called when the device orientation goes to landscape mode. Should I be using this method or could this be achieved using a different approach?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let sectionAttributes = SectionAttributesFactory.createSectionAttributes(for: indexPath.section)
        
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            print("Section: \(sectionAttributes.type) | lanscape: \(sectionAttributes.cellLayout.landscapeSize.width)")
        } else {
            print("Section: \(sectionAttributes.type) | portrait: \(sectionAttributes.cellLayout.portraitSize.width)")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`  is called when the viewController first loads and when the collectionView's layout is invalidated. You typically want to invalidate the layout in `viewWillTransition(to:with:)`

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    })
}
```

Then you can make changes to cell sizes based on the device orientation and view size:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cellsPerRow = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait ? CGFloat(3.0) : CGFloat(4.0)
    let spacing = layout.minimumInteritemSpacing * (cellsPerRow - 1)
    let cellWidth = (view.frame.size.width - spacing) / cellsPerRow
    return .init(uniform: cellWidth)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll look into this function.